# statistics for image processing/computer vision

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision

I came across this information while searching for distribution functions in physics.

[image: stats for physics]

so, i was wondering if similar diagram was to be used for image processing/computer vision, what all distributions would it consist of??
I can only think of Gaussian distribution right now.

source of above image: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/math/statcon.html#c1

I found out boost supports these distributions in c++..not sure if stl has any support for these yet.

Comment: This paper might be useful? http://www.academia.edu/637130/Image_Processing_Research_Opportunities_and_Challenges

Comment: I could not find any statistical information in that paper..no talk about gaussian mixture models, markov random fields etc..there is significant statistics used in computer vision and medical imaging...anyway, i will make a list pretty soon and post whatever i know so far..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Statistics help for computer vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745559/statistics-help-for-computer-vision)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Histogram
  -- used for checking the intensity distribution in an image.
    example: Contrast Enhancement in HSV color space.
- Gaussian Distribution
  -- used for modelling randomness noise, which can then be used for 
    noise reduction.
- Mixture Models
  -- used for modelling, while differentiating foreground/background pixels
    in a image segmentation phase

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer I provided for getting started with statistics for computer vision:

[Statistics help for computer vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745559/statistics-help-for-computer-vision/64773218#64773218)

Comment: Instead of linking your other answer here as an answer, flag the question as duplicate. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers — Your other answer is fantastic, by the way.